# Open Office Base Macros

Tags: open-office

Подскажите, как в Open Office Base добавить запись в выбранную таблицу открытого документа при помощи макроса на языке BASIC? В документации не описана система объекта документа Base, подскажите, где ее можно найти

Comment: А там хоть какая-то описана?

Comment: Нет, только описание языка.